# How to generate clojure code to call java method at run time?

Tags: java, clojure

I want to use Java reflection method with in Clojure function.
I think the code like `(.toString {:a 1})`  will parse and compile by clojure reader. So, it works by use clojure macro. But if I want to define a function to call java object method at run time , it failed.  I have no idea how to invoke this kind of code with in clojure.

Here is my demo code:

```
 (def jmethod ".toString")
 (defn call-java-method [mname & body]
     (let [fn1 (fn [] `(~(symbol mname) ~@body))]
        (fn1)))

 user=> (call-java-method jmethod 3.4M)
```

The result is a list `(.toString 3.4M)` , but I want to eval this list as a clojure function call.

Answer (score 1):

As you have realized, since macros 'operate at compile-time', you essentially can't use them to call a dynamically-resolved method.

You have 2 options:

1. use the Java [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)
2. use [`clojure.core/eval`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/eval), which consists using Clojure as a runtime compiler to compile your code, then execute it.